# How to use stream on method that return boolean value with condition

Tags: java, list, java-stream, conditional-statements

I am using this method:

```
public boolean checkRowsFilterNameBy(String filter){
    waitForElmContainsText(searchButton, "Search");
    List<AuditRow> listRows = auditTable.getTable();
    for(AuditRow row : listRows){
        if(!row.nameStr.equals(filter)||!row.nameStr.contains(filter))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and I want to be able to change it using Stream , I've tried the following, but I am missing something:

```
listRows.stream().forEach(auditRow -> {
           if(auditRow.actionStr.equals(filter))return true;} else return false;);
```

but I am getting an error.

Comment: Why use a `stream`  if you are just replacing a loop for a `forEach`? see also: https://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/08/3-reasons-why-you-shouldnt-replace-your-for-loops-by-stream-foreach/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
listRows.stream().allMatch(row -> row.nameStr.equals(filter) && row.nameStr.contains(filter));
```

**Update**

As per Holgers suggestion, this can be further simplified as this.

```
listRows.stream().allMatch(row -> row.nameStr.contains(filter));
```

The use of `equals` or `contains` may vary depending on your context.

Comment: I think at the same time I have updated the answer. Thanks !

Comment: @nullpointer that might be a correct code transformation, but just reveals a logical error in the OP’s condition. `equals(filter)` implies `contains(filter)`, so if all strings must be equal, there is no point in also testing `contains(filter)`.

Comment: In that case we can merely dispense with `&& row.nameStr.contains(filter)`

Comment: Depends on the actual intention. Perhaps, the intended logic is `contains(filter)`, in which case `equals(filter)` should be removed. In either case, testing for both makes no sense (that would apply to combining via `||` as well).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a stream filter to filter out all elements that are true and do a count on the result.

```
boolean result = (listRows.stream().filter(row -> row.nameStr.equals(filter) && row.nameStr.contains(filter)).count() == 0);
```

Comment: but that is not the purpose I want to check all the list items and check if they follow the condition and if so true will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of all the negations using de-morgan's law such that

```
(!a || !b) => !(a && b)
```

you can use `allMatch` as:

```
return listRows.stream()
        .allMatch(row -> row.nameStr.equals(filter)
                && row.nameStr.contains(filter));
```

which has a similar version using noneMatch :

```
return listRows.stream()
        .noneMatch(row -> (!row.nameStr.equals(filter) 
                || !row.nameStr.contains(filter)));
```

A logical improvement in your code could further be to just check for `contains` which would imply `equal`ity as well, this would cut down to:

```
return listRows.stream().allMatch(row -> row.nameStr.contains(filter));
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, if any of the conditions become true

```
return listRows.stream().anyMatch(row -> !row.nameStr.equals(filter) || !row.nameStr.contains(filter)) // boolean;
```